# How to use custom Javascript code inside a plugin?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, javascript, scripts

So, I have a custom Javascript code that inserts a pop-up widget in a webpage. The source code is irrelevant but it works by manually pasting before the `<\body>` tag of the website, such that:

```
<body>
   /*
   do something
   */
   <script type="text/javascript" id="widget-code">
       /*
       widget pops up
       */
   </script>
<\body>
```

What I want to do is include that script in the plugin that I'm developing  so that the widget will appear in all webpages of the Wordpress site. How do I do such?

```
/**
* Plugin Name: Test Plugin
* Plugin URI: http://example.com
* Description: test plugin
* Author: John Doe
**/
```

If I'm not mistaken, this is essentially a task of pasting the script before the `<\body>` tag  in all webpages but inside a plugin?

Comment: Check out the docs and examples for [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Answer (score 1):

Look into [wp_register_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) and [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). You may be able to get by with only the latter.

Pay special attention for your case of wanting it before the closing `</body>` that you can specify `in_footer` as a parameter.

```
wp_enqueue_script(  $handle, //(string) name of script
                    $src = '', // uri to script
                    $deps = array(), //handles of other scripts this script is dependent on
                    $ver = '1.0', version number of script 
                    $in_footer = true //if script should be in footer
                   )
```

You can hook the above via the [`wp_enqueue_scripts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/)

```
function enqueue_your_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )  . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_your_scripts' );
```

In the above, `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )` is returning the plugin directory the file is in, and we're assuming a subdirectory of `/js/` and a file named `example.js`